# le vendeur a pas à s’acquitter de la taxe foncière

Tags: sens

Google translate translates this sentence as ‘the seller does not have to pay the property tax’.

I am interested in the ‘a pas à’ part.

Avoir pas à = to not have to?

If so, why is ‘ne’ not present here. The [reference article](https://www.economie.gouv.fr/particuliers/viager-comment-ca-marche#) is written in formal French and so dropping ‘ne’ is not expected.

Can someone please help? Merci !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a mistake in the original text. It should be:

> Le vendeur **n**'a pas à s’acquitter de la taxe foncière.

Answer (score 0):

Réponse exacte!! L'omission du ''ne'' dans une négation toute ordinaire relève en l'occurrence de l'emploi familier courant négligent tout à fait déplacé à l'écrit habituel convenable.